# Android ListItem's item popup alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, listadapter, listitem

I have a twist on a common question I've seen in here, and I'm puzzled.

What I need is simply a dialog box for each sub item of a list item. I have seen a dialog for a list item, but I need it down to the list item's item. Currently I've tried doing that within the adapter when inside the getView() method.

For example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(_resourceId, null);
    }

    string description = "howdy Test";

    TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
    description.setText(description );
    description.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder dia = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            dia.setTitle(view.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.DESCRIPTION_TITLE));
            dia.create();
        }
    });
}
```

With that example above, it does go into the onClick() method, but nothing happens with the AlertDialog. Has anyone else tried this? is there a better way? Even better what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Kelly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the `show()` method on your **dia** object.[Link here to the android docs!](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#show%28%29)

Comment: Bam! That did the trick for me. Thank you very much Slukian, I really appreciate it. I knew it had to be something simple, but it just wasn't clicking with me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a OnClickListener to each item in the list view why don't you add one to the listview itself?

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id){

        // Create and show dialog here

    }
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't have helped in my case. I needed it on a individual level within the list item vs the list item as a whole.